# ::after SVG showing in Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: css

I am wanting to implement an svg using the ::after pseudo-element. When I run my code, it works perfectly in Firefox,
[image]

but in Chrome the svg (down arrow) is non-existent.

[image]

There were quite a few questions and answers regarding this problem, but every one of them addressed a code issue that others were having and did not pertain to me.
My code follows:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="select-box">
     <div class="acronym">DRY</div>
     <div>Don't Repeat Yourself</div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.select-box {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;

    & .acronym {
        width: 55px;
        color: #c29b69;
    }
}

.select-box::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("/arrow.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 22%;
    width: 3.2rem;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

I appologize. I wanted to include a codepen of the issue, but that would involve asset hosting to include the svg, which is a Pro plan. I am not a professional - just an amateur passionate about coding. Thanks for any help you can offer-up.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works - albeit with a different arrow SVG - on Chrome/Edge/Firefox on Windows 10. SO (imgur) does not allow SVGs to be loaded so the pointer SVG is hosted as a temporary one and won't be there forever.

```css
.select-box {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .acronym {
        width: 55px;
        color: #c29b69;
}

.select-box::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("https://ahweb.org.uk/temp2.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 22%;
    width: 3.2rem;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="select-box">
     <div class="acronym">DRY</div>
     <div>Don't Repeat Yourself</div>
 </div>
```

So what can be the problem? The only thing I can think of is that there is some problem either with using a 3d rotation on your particular SVG (?backface-visibility - though the default should be set at visible) or the rotation about the X axis is flipping the SVG out of the containing element.

Could you try first not having any transform on the pointer to see if it is visible, and then trying a rotate(180deg) instead (i.e. about the z-axis) so there's no worry about what is happening, or not, in 3D and so that the image stays in place rather than moving down.

Comment: Hey A. I tried the suggestions with no luck but thank you. I put my code on GitLab. https://gitlab.com/don199/svg-as-after-pseudo-element                                                       
If you run the code on live-server the issue presents itself. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. I have copied your arrow svg and used it in the snippet. It is working fine I cannot see a problem - the only thing is if you copy and edit the snippet through the SO system the arrow is hidden under the snippet editor's 'Result' heading - but you can see it if you just run the snippet here. So - what else could be creating your problem?

Comment: PS - I tried it on Chrome/Edge on Windows 10.

Comment: Narrowed down. The svg works fine using standard file set-up (index, style) but when it is placed in a file that contains the node_modules and sass folder, the svg doesn't display. Any last suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like it isn’t being referenced properly.

Answer (score 0):

As A Haworth pointed out, it was a reference issue. I was applying the svg via the background:url(); property for the first time. It worked well with just an html and css file with background: url("img/arrow.svg"). But the trouble was that I was trying to reference the svg the same way when using node/sass. The proper way to reference it in that case was background: url("../img/arrow.svg"). Thanks for the heads-up A Hawthorn. That led me to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577084/background-image-url-works-on-live-server-but-when-i-open-the-index-html-in-th),